# Entity of type 'App\Entity\Slider' for IDs id(45) was not found

Tags: symfony, entity

Hello everybody I need some help for a exception who is appeared on my project (symfony mvc)

The console return a http 500 when I have wanted to add a slider in a actuality post.

Slider and Actuality are two differents entities.

I have tried to understand the problem but **i don't found**. :/[in the ActualityController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoUoI.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeNlF.png)

Comment: pls share your code

Comment: Since the exception comes from the `ChoiceLoader`, it looks like the `Slider` 45 was deleted but still associated with an `Actuality`.